# Remove trailing space in a cell

Tags: excel, trailing

I have a bunch of cells with a trailing space after the value. I tried using =clean however this did not remove it. Does anyone know another way of removing that?

Comment: Use `=TRIM(A1)`

Comment: If trim does not work alone try `=TRIM(CLEAN(A1))`

Comment: That did it, thank you!!